# how to find matches with regExp

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to find matches with this example:

user input: fi ma // regExp(/???/gi)

result: **fi**nd **ma**tches

Which expression should i use?

Comment: Do you only want to select two letters, or up to two? Would to word `a` be matched?

Comment: Specifically "fi ma" or the first 2 letters of every word?

Comment: any number of letters, it's like search in webstorm ide

Answer (score 0):

> \b\w{2}

will get the first 2 letters of each word. `\b` creates a boundry around characters separated by white space, i.e. words, and `\w{2}` matches exactly 2 word characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/\bfi[^\s]*\s*\bma[^\s]*/g`

Example of usage: https://regex101.com/r/oH3uA0/3

---

### Explained:

`\b` matches a word boundary(where a word character is not followed or preceeded by another word-character). Useful for beginning of words

`*[^\s]` matches the rest of the first word.

In this manner, you can use `\bfoo[^\s]+\s` to match words beginning with foo up until the start of the next word.

Same repeats for the second word. You can also chain these to match more words beginning with strings of your choice (i.e. to match a chain of 3 words that begin with **foo, bar, dar** respecfully, you would use `/\bfoo[^\s]*\s*\bbar[^\s]*\s*\bdar[^\s]*/g`